# How to handle Server Error in React-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I use GraphQL-Yoga as a backend.
The format of the Errors that it returns does not match the documentation. But I need their translation. Is there one place in `React -admin` where I could catch all the errors from the server and make them as expected by the Notification component?

```
Error:{
    extraInfo: undefined
    graphQLErrors: {
        locations: [{ column: 3, line: 2 }]
        message: "User with such login does not exist."
        path: ["login"]
    }
    message: "GraphQL error: User with such login does not exist."
    networkError: null
    stack: "Error: GraphQL error: User with such login does not exist.↵    at new ApolloError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:39388:24)↵    at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:38008:21)↵    at notifySubscription (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:270732:18)↵    at onNotify (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:270776:3)↵    at SubscriptionObserver.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:270828:7)↵    at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:47919:22)↵    at notifySubscription (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:270732:18)↵    at onNotify (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:270776:3)↵    at SubscriptionObserver.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:270828:7)↵    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:48354:18"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue with loopback as it sends the error inside an error object instead of directly in the message attribute of the response. What I did was the following:

Create your own httpClient, as in the docs for setting your auth token.

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    // ...
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://localhost:3000/api', httpClient);
```

In your Admin component:

```
<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
```

Then you need to create your own fetchJson implementation:

```
import { HttpError } from 'react-admin';

const fetchJson = async (url, options = {}) => {
    const requestHeaders = (options.headers ||
        new Headers({
            Accept: 'application/json',
        })
    );
    if (!requestHeaders.has('Content-Type') &&
        !(options && options.body && options.body instanceof FormData)) {
        requestHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    if (options.user && options.user.authenticated && options.user.token) {
        requestHeaders.set('Authorization', options.user.token);
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, { ...options, headers: requestHeaders })
    const text = await response.text()
    const o = {
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText,
        headers: response.headers,
        body: text,
    };
    let status = o.status, statusText = o.statusText, headers = o.headers, body = o.body;
    let json;
    try {
        json = JSON.parse(body);
    } catch (e) {
        // not json, no big deal
    }
    if (status < 200 || status >= 300) {
        return Promise.reject(new HttpError((json && json.error && json.error.message) || statusText, status, json));
    }
    return Promise.resolve({ status: status, headers: headers, body: body, json: json });
};
```

This is actually just a copy of fetchUtils.fetchJson, but notice:

```
return Promise.reject(new HttpError((json && json.error && json.error.message) || statusText, status, json));
```

This is where you should set your error message from the json response.

Finally you just need to change fetchUtils.fetchJson to your fetchJson method:

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    // ...
    return fetchJson(url, options); // <--- change this line
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work for ra-data-graphql-simple (

Comment: When I throw a HTTP error it logs me out of a react-admin session

Comment: @BenWinding Do a Promise.reject("a string or a translation key") It will then display it in the notification popup without crashing

Comment: Hi @Hettomei,
I did end up fixing this, my dataprovider was not properly handling errors. I will add my fix below

Answer (score 1):

My problem, was that I was not properly throwing the error in the DataProvider, here's how I got react-admin displaying the HTTP errors:

```js
import { GET_LIST } from "react-admin";

async function providerApi(type, resourceName, params) {
  let res;
  try {
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST:
        res = await MyGetList(resourceName, params);
        break;
      /* All other methods */
    }
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMsg = error.toString();
    const code = translateErrorMessageToCode(errorMsg);
    const errorObj = { status: code, message: errorMsg, json: res };
    throw errorObj;
  }
}

function translateErrorMessageToCode(errorMsg) {
  if (errorMsg.includes('unauthenticated')) {
    return 401
  }
  if (errorMsg.includes('aborted')) {
    return 409
  }
  if (errorMsg.includes('not-found')) {
    return 404
  }
  return 200
}
```

Comment: omg thank you, I had to include `data: errorMsg` to the return object in order for react-admin v3.8.2 read it properly on the frontend, but your solution worked.