# Translating react-admin network error notifications

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to display a custom translated notification when the API throws an exception.

By default, when getting a 409 conflict response, `react-admin` shows a red notification with the text "Conflict" (see attached screenshot).

How can I translate this message?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking generally how to translate error messages or are you wanting to give more detailed error messages?

Comment: I'd like to show an error message based on the value of the error object in the 409 response (in this case, `email_already_exists`). Not just a default message for the given HTTP code, in this case "Conflict".

Answer (score 1):

React-admin passes server error messages through its `translate` function, which relies on the `i18nProvider` (see [The translation chapter](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html) in the react-admin documentation).

So if your server returns an error message that is a valid translation message (e.g. 'server.create_error.conflict') and you use Polyglot as i18nProvider, you just need to include the following translation in your messages:

```json
{
  server: {
    create_error: {
       conflict: 'Impossible to create element: email already exists'
    }
  }
}
```

See [Mixing interface and domain translations](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#mixing-interface-and-domain-translations) for more details.

Comment: Thank-you for the reply. In this example, our API returns the error response as `{"error":"email_already_used"}`. How should the translation look in my `i18nProvider.js` file?

Comment: `{ email_already_used: "Email already used" }`

Comment: Thanks but not having much luck here. Under what top-level key should this be under? i.e. `const sv = { ra: { notification: { email_already_used: "Email already used" } } }`

Comment: Does it work if you put it at the root level?

Comment: I've tried putting it at many different levels, including root, and it still doesn't work. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it worked for me.

- From the server, API throws the error - `err.login.duplicate`
- In react-admin, err.js file has the following:

> export const err = { login: { duplicate: "Email is already in use" } }

- Note that I had to write my own fetchJson to be able to read the error object and throw it to the user.  Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508741/how-to-handle-server-error-in-react-admin)
- This way, react-admin throws "Email is already in use" error.